# Access to element in javascript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

After

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        var arr = [];
        for(var x in parsed){
          arr.push(parsed[x]);
        }
```

I have:

```
arr = [{"text":"sometext"}]
[{"text":"sometextOne"},{"text":"sometextTwo"}]
[{"text":"sometextOther"},{"text":"sometext"}]
[{"text":"sometexts"}]
[{"text":"sometextThree"},{"text":"sometextOne"},{"text":"sometextTwo"}]
```

What the best way show 'sometext' ?

Example: console.log(array.text) // sometext

Comment: your code is not valid json

Comment: why stringify? please add the original array.

Comment: Do not stringify your arr variable and refer to it

Comment: Which "sometext"?

Comment: `console.log("sometext")`

Comment: please add the content of `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array[0].text` its a way to show sometext.

If your json array should be like this

`var arr=[
    {"text":"sometext"}, 
    {"text":"sometext"},
    {"text":"sometext"}
]`

U can use this code to print sometext

`for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {console.log(arr[i].text);}`

Comment: But this is show only one 'sometext', but what if is two or more 'sometext' ?

Comment: Because it is after JSON.stringify(arr)